# Using CROSS JOIN to add extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

This is a followup question to my previous question:
[Identifier could not be bound in multiple common table expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908896/identifier-could-not-be-bound-in-multiple-common-table-expressions)

I want to add a column called "Overall Average" to display the overall shipping days for all rows using CROSS JOIN:

```
WITH orderDetails (days, state) 
AS(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(day, o.OrderDate, ol.ShipDate), o.State 
    FROM SQLBook.dbo.Orders o
    JOIN [SQLBook].dbo.OrderLines ol
    ON ol.OrderId = o.OrderId
)
,
/* This finds the overall average shipping days */
AvgShipping (avgShip)
AS(
    SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, o.OrderDate, ol.ShipDate))
    FROM SQLBook.dbo.Orders o
    JOIN [SQLBook].dbo.OrderLines ol
    ON ol.OrderId = o.OrderId
)

SELECT
    ord.state,
    AVG(ord.days) AS "Average days to ship",
    a.[Overall Average] AS "Overall Average"
FROM orderDetails ord
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT avgShip AS "Overall Average" FROM AvgShipping) a
GROUP BY state
HAVING AVG(days) > (SELECT avgShip FROM AvgShipping)
ORDER BY state
```

However I got a "Column 'a.Overall Average' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" Error. Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.

Comment: Use min(a.[Overall Average]) in your select. This should resolve the issue and should get you the output desired.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Somy, it worked!

Comment: Let me put it in the answer so that you can mark it as answered, so that the post is resolved. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had suggested in the comment, use in your select.

```
 min(a.[Overall Average])
```

This should resolve the issue and should get you the output desired.

This would ensure aggregate function being used for a column that is in select and not in group by. Also, since you are extracting the field from cross-join you can use any aggregate function such as min, max etc, the result/output would be the same.